# pandas - updating a dataframe column with value of another column with if condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to update ColumnA if it have "0" and string "pandas" in ColumnC with the mean value [which i stored in columnB]

```
df['ColumnA'] = df.apply(lambda x: x['ColumnB'] if (x['ColumnA']==0 & x['ColumnC']=='pandas') else x['ColumnA'], axis=1)
```

I am getting this error

```
unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'int' and 'str'
```

kindly advise how i can fix it

Comment: Use `and` instead of `&`: `(x['ColumnA']==0 and x['ColumnC']=='pandas')` `&` is for pandas Series but since you are applying through rows `x['ColumnA']` is a python scalar, so you can't use `&`.

Answer (score 0):

Put parentheses around your conditions, and as pointed out in the comments, use and instead of & for scalar comparison, e.g.

```py
((x['ColumnA'] == 0) and (x['ColumnC'] == 'pandas'))
```

See [this question on order of operations](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42338154/3888719) - the bitwise operator `&` takes precedence over the boolean operator `==`

That said, you should consider using a vectorized operation:

```py
df['ColumnA'] = df['ColumnB'].where(
    ((df['ColumnA'] == 0) & (df['ColumnC'] == 'pandas')),
    df['ColumnA'],
)
```

This will be faster than df.apply in nearly all cases.

Answer (score 0):

Use `and` instead of `&` and also put brackets around the `==` tests:

```
df['ColumnA'] = df.apply(lambda x: x['ColumnB'] if (x['ColumnA']==0) and (x['ColumnC']=='pandas') else x['ColumnA'], axis=1)
```