# Why pandas boolean series needs () to work with boolean operators?

Tags: python, pandas, series

I've seen that if you pass a boolean series to a dataframe of the same length as rows in the dataframe it filters the dataframe. However, if we pass a condition instead of a boolean series (like `df['col']==value`) and want to perform boolean operations on that condition  (like ~ ) it does not work, even though the condition's result is a boolean series. It only works if it is surrounded by parenthesis. In other words, this works `df[~(df['col']>value)]` and this does not `df[~df['col']>value]`, notice the only difference are the parenthesis

I thought the parenthesis was doing something to the boolean series resulting from applying `df['col']>value`, like casting it into another kind of object that supports operations such as `~`. But it does not, the `type(df['col']>value)` and `type((df['col']>value))` is the same, whcih is "pandas.core.series.Series". So what are those parenthesis doing that enables the boolean series resulting from using the condition?

Moreover, if you have two boolean_series derived from applying conditions to a dataframe, like

`series_a=df['col']>value` and `series_b=df['col']==value` and you try to use both of them with an `&` operator this way `df[series_a & series_b]` it actually works fine. But calculating them inside the dataframe does not works `df[df['col']>value & df['col']==value]` , it gives error `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'int' and 'IntegerArray'`
From that error I would assume there is some precedence in the operators taking place since it seems it's trying to apply the & to an IntegerArray, probably doing this: `df['col']> (value & df['col']) ==value` But I would like to ask to confirm

Example:
Supposing we have some dataframe with column `tag` that has either values A or B

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import random

df=pd.DataFrame({'tag'=[random.choice['A','B' for i in range(100)]}
```

If I try to filter doing this:

```
df[~(df['tag']=='A')]
```

It works, but If I do this without those parenthesis it does not works with this error `TypeError: bad operand type for unary ~: 'str'`

```
df[~df['tag']=='A']
```

Comment: `~df['tag']=='A'` is equivalent to `(~df['tag'])=='A'`

Comment: `df=pd.DataFrame({'tag'=[random.choice['A','B' for i in range(100)]}` has lots of syntax and logic problems. Please show what you actually used.

Comment: It's because Python's bitwise operators have higher precedence than Python's comparison operators. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42338005/pandas-logical-and-operator-with-and-without-brackets-produces-different-results

Comment: You need to check the operator precedence table when you remove parentheses, to understand how the result will be parsed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its a question of [Operator precedence](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence). When you provide two operations (`~` and `>`), python has to decide which one to apply first. In

```
~df['col']>value
```

`~` has higher precedence so it goes first. You negated the dataframe and then compared. Its the same as `(~(df['col'])) > value`.

If you want to compare and then negate, you have to use parentheses to avoid the unwanted order of operations. Expressions inside parens have the highest precedence. In

```
~(df['col']>value)
```

the comparison is done first.